# Problem coming while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (32 Bit) iso file from ubuntu.com. Made a Bootable Pen Drive using Universal USB Installer & tried to install on my Desktop(Configuration: Intel Pentium 4 with Hyper-threading Enabled having 1280 MB DDR1 RAM). I also tried it on DVD Drive & Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS image file **but always file missing or corrupted error comes & installation fails**. Please help so that I can install Ubuntu 14.04 or even Ubuntu 12.04 on my System.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file again and check that it is correct by following the instructions on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).